# Javascript EventListener is envoked by by its own

Tags: javascript, events

I have a piece of code that is supposed to change the text color whenever user clicks on the text. But text color is changed before user clicks on the text.
It seems that click event is called before user does it !!!
Please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
var div = document.getElementById("div1"); // there is html div inside of html file with id "div1"
div.innerHTML = "Hello world";

function colorChange(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.color="red";

};

div.addEventListener("click",colorChange("div1"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually **calling** the function as soon as you're creating your event handler.
Notice your code `div.addEventListener('click', colorChange('div1'))` <-- it's the fact that you have `()` paranthesis there (which calls the function).

You need to pass in an anonymous function instead.

```
div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    colorChange("div1")
});
```